# Using Selenium or Request in Python doesn't read all span class

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

Why didn't I get all the HTML code when using Request or Selenium to scrape the e-commerce website?

So, here's my code:

```
html = "https://www.tokopedia.com/p/fashion-anak-bayi/pakaian-anak-laki-laki/baju-tidur-anak-laki-laki?page=1&wholesale=true&goldmerchant=true&fcity=174,175,176,177,178,179"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36 RuxitSynthetic/1.0 v6366394992 t38550 ath9b965f92 altpub',
          "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
          "DNT": "1",
          "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
web = requests.get(html,headers=header, data=data)
pageweb = BeautifulSoup(web.content, 'html.parser')
#Get name and Location
store_loc = pageweb.find_all('span',{'class':'css-1kr22w3'})
```

But, the result doesn't appear for all of div class span. If I go with Selenium, then the answer is still the same.

The class what I'm looking for didn't appear in all of them.

I'm using this code to fulfill my curiosity about scraping and get the data.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: take out `, data=data` and it produces 20 results, same as Firefox inspect finds.

Comment: I just take out the data, but is not working. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.tokopedia.com/p/fashion-anak-bayi/pakaian-anak-laki-laki/baju-tidur-anak-laki-laki?page=1&wholesale=true&goldmerchant=true&fcity=174,175,176,177,178,179"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36 RuxitSynthetic/1.0 v6366394992 t38550 ath9b965f92 altpub',
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"
}
page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
store_loc = page.find_all('span', {'class': 'css-1kr22w3'})
print(len(store_loc))

for tag in store_loc:
    print(tag.text)
```

Output of `20` items.

```
Jakarta Utara
Chloe Clozette
Jakarta Utara
Chloe Clozette
Jakarta Barat
AICOMFY Collection
...
```

Comment: Yeah it just 20 but there are 50 text in html if you inspect the elements in your browser. Thank you for the response anyway!